# Why does applying generics such as Omit<T, K> to a function cause it to not be callable?

Tags: typescript

I was playing around with TypeScript and found that applying `Omit<T, K>` on a callable function, makes it no longer callable:

```
declare function myCallableFunction(): void;

myCallableFunction(); // valid

type NonOmittedFunction = typeof myCallableFunction;
declare const myNonOmittedFunction: NonOmittedFunction;
myNonOmittedFunction(); // valid

type OmittedFunction = Omit<typeof myCallableFunction, 'foobar'>;
declare const myOmittedFunction: OmittedFunction;
myOmittedFunction(); // This expression is not callable.
                    //  Type 'OmittedFunction' has no call signatures.
```

Why is this?

Here is a heavily contrived example as to where you may want to do something like this:

```
declare type CallCountingFunction = (() => void) & { count: number }
const myFunction: CallCountingFunction = (() => { 
                                            const x = () => {}; 
                                            x.count = 0; 
                                            return x;
                                         })()

myFunction.count; // valid
myFunction() // valid
type OmittedFunction = Omit<CallCountingFunction, 'count'>;
declare const myOmittedFunction: OmittedFunction;
myOmittedFunction(); // This expression is not callable.
                    //  Type 'OmittedFunction' has no call signatures.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAXAngBwQYShCGD2ArgHaICWRA5gGLFhl5HwC88AFKwJTMB88AbnlLAuAMngBveGEIkAXPCIEAtgCMQMeAF8AsAChpRAM6J4S5DSJ1SDeVhz5iZShasNmbTjwnw98P-4DAoOCQkINjeAAPd08mXnFNAG4fXVC09Iy-SIA6aUd3AAZk30zSsvg4RAIYRkjEkvLGoM0OTj09Mxd6IlyZRGSAegH+bCEO81puzyGRiDHdFHR4AHklUkREEGAu60YWVfWAHjtcPvJqSd2AGngAcjySW+563VBIWARwkzMDja2dmwrNZ-baXBgvH7AzagyxTDiDYYAFQAFqRDPAQJFUHBDIZdvA0Qo8CYwNhoCoICBsg1GjN4Ii0Ahbr9oQCiLd4MioOiiHgpGT4HiKEQoFUcdkgA)

This appears to be true for *all* generic utility types that involve remapping such as `Partial<T>` and `Required<T>`.

Comment: Does using `Exclude` instead of `Omit` work?

Comment: @IainShelvington It's valid, but `Exclude` operates on unions, not individual types which means it has no effect on my `CallCountingFunction` type.

Comment: Call signatures do not have keys. A simpler example at the core of why this doesn't work: https://tsplay.dev/w1PLKW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The utility types aren't magic, they're actually all written in Typescript and we can view them. [`Omit`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1574) is defined in terms of `Pick` and `Exclude`.

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof any> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

Nothing crazy yet, but [`Pick`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1550) is defined as

```
type Pick<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    [P in K]: T[P];
};
```

So `Pick<T, K>` is *always* defined to be an object type with indexed keys. There's no call signature here. It's easy to *think* of `Omit` as "take my type `T` and remove some specific things", but internally it really is "create a new object type that has `T`'s keys, minus some things", and since the ability to call a function is not an object key, it doesn't get transferred. The analogy breaks down since functions are, fundamentally, not really designed to be used this way.